# Thread safety of logging to same file using different handlers/logger instances

Tags: multithreading, file, logging, thread-safety, handler

I am writing a basic Flask application to accept GET requests. It's not relevant how the GET requests are handled, just that everything is happening in one Python process, and that there's just one function which is routed to handle GET requests.

Suppose I want to log the parameters of the GET request. I want to be able to safely log to the same file in multiple "threads" created from concurrent GET requests. I have read that Python's logging is thread-safe, but I do not understand the conditions in which this is true.

For example, is it safe to log to the same file using different handlers/logger instances without using locks or anything like that? Is it safe to log to the same file from different threads using the same file handler but different logger instances?

I did not try anything yet because concurrency issues are inconsistent and I didn't want to rely on testing it as a means for ensuring its safety

Comment: Why do you put "threads" in double quotes? Is your webserver even multithreaded? Also, which logger are you using? And where did you read that this specific logger is safe to be used concurrently? Generally, two programs (or parts of one program) writing to the same file without synchronization can corrupt the output file by interleaving data.

Comment: What OS?  On POSIX systems, a single [`write()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) to a file open in append mode is guaranteed to be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Each `logging.Handler` instance has its own `Lock` that ensures thread-safe usage.

So if you create a single `logging.Handler`, you can add it to as many loggers as you like, and use it from as many threads as you like, and access to the underlying file will be completely safe.

Creating **multiple** `logging.Handler` instances pointing to the **same** file is not thread-safe, however.